# How to access the TelemetryClient singleton instance in startup for ASP.NET core app

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET Core Web App that uses Application Insights for telemetry. I would like to wrap the TelemetryClient object with my own interface and add that instance to the services collection. To do this I need access to the singleton instance of Telemetry client in startup.cs. I can get the service information with this code:

```
        var info = services.Where(x => x.ServiceType.Name == "TelemetryClient").Single();
```

That info has a ImplementationInstance that I would expect to find the instance in, but it is null. Is there any way to get the singleton instance of this item so I can create my wrapper class instance with it? My other option is to create the wrapper class in my controller constructors because there I can access it from the services container via this code:

HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(T)) as T;

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you do this?

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Wrapper(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
         // Handle init
    }
}
```

And register that in the service collection:

```
services.AddTransient<Wrapper>();
```

You can then get the Wrapper in your controllers through the constructor.

If this does not work for you, please leave a comment and explain why.

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar to this. I create a wrapper around the TelemetryClient that has an interface and an implementation. The implementation class takes the TelemetryClient as a  constructor. The interface is IAppTelemetry and the implementation is AppTelemetry. I register the instance with this:

services.AddSingleton<IAppTelemetry, AppTelemetry>();